# Is it worth upgrading from High Sierra to Monterey in macbook Pro?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, high-sierra, monterey

I'm using `MacBook Pro with macOS High Sierra Version 10.13.6`

```
MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2016, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports)

Processor 2 GHz Intel Core i5
Memory 8GB 1867 MHz
Graphis Intel Iris Graphics
```

I'm not able to update most of the softwares/apps, everyday I get some notifications that I have to update `OS High Sierra to Monterey`.

I would like to know whether it is worth to update the `OS High Sierra to Monterey`.

In case if I need to update, just doing a backup of all my data is fine or should I also do anything else before OS update?

Any suggestions please. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You need to get off of High Sierra, only because High Sierra is no longer receiving security updates.  What you want to upgrade to, is up to you.

Catalina will stop security updates in Q4 2022 (most likely)

Big Sur will stop security updates in Q4 2023 (again, most likely)

Monterey is currently still receiving "feature" updates.

Answer (score 1):

Always make a **current** and **full** backup before doing any upgrade.

I have done many upgrades and all have completed successfully without destroying my data. HOWEVER I still do the backup prior just in case. You only have to look on here to see how many are not so lucky.

Comment: Should I also do backup of all the applications I'm using? Or only data related to me is fine?

Comment: @SolarMike Should be making backups regularly anyway, regardless of upgrades.  I'm sure you know that already.